# pgtypes.fetcher is not a function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, postgis

I have been trying to implement [pg-postgis-types npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-postgis-types) in my express project for my internship. I'm using PostgreSQL and Sequelize.

Unfortunately, although I have implemented the code in the documentation, our API returns `pgtypes.fetcher is not a function`. Does anyone encounter with this issue? I checked the definition of the package in node modules folder and I found the definition, as it should be.

To be a reference, my code is like below.

```
const getgeojson = async (mapID) => {
    try {
        postgis(pgtypes.fetcher(pg, connection), null, (err, oids) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            };  ...
```

I know this is not a much popular repo but maybe someone encounter and solved it before, I just wanted to ask. Sorry if this is a bad question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package is much older, thus, the usage is slightly different from the original documentation in both npm and GitHub repo. You can call functions by changing `postgis`to `postgis.default` and `pgtypes.fetcher` to `pgtypes.default.fetcher`. This solved my stated issue above. Have a nice day y'all.